# Have a String of letters with different font sizes - LineLegend

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation, legending, labeling

There's a Plot whose legend has symbols with subscripts and regular text. The words that have subscripts appear to shrink in size and looks out of place in comparison to the rest of the legend.

Was looking up, and it doesn't seem like I can have different sizes inside a string.

In general I use `FrameLabel` defined like this for the legends

```
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(2g\)]\)  Element", FontFamily -> "TeX Gyre Pagella",  FontSize -> 22]
```

Is there a way I could have `\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(2g\)]\)` in font size 26 and the rest in 22? `StringJoin` doesn't work and I am unsure what type of thing `Style` is.

Thought it could work with `Graphics`, but at least how I tried it doesn't seem to work. My idea was to create a `GraphicsRow` with the two different texts of different sizes.

```
plot1=Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3} , Frame -> True];
tex1 = Style["Element ", FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "TeX Gyre Pagella"];
tex2 = Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(g\)]\)    Element", FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "TeX Gyre Pagella"];
tex3 = Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(g\)]\)", FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "TeX Gyre Pagella"];
legend1 = GraphicsRow[{tex2}]
legend2 = GraphicsRow[{tex3, tex1}]


Legended[ Show[ plot1, ImageSize->850,PlotRange->{{0.1, 1.02},{-0.05,5.3}}, 
Epilog ->  {Directive[{Black, Dashing[0.02]}],Line[{{0.820,0},{0.820,6}}]},
Prolog-> Inset[Style[inset,Magnification>0.6], Scaled[{0.25,0.76}], Scaled[{0.5,0.5}], Scaled[{1,1}]]], 
Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Black, Magnification->3.5], Directive[Red, Magnification->3.5]}, {legend2,legend2}], Scaled[{0.58, 0.16}]]]
```

The legend has a lot of extra vertical space because of `GraphicsRow` but it does allow me to have a higher font size for the words with subscripts. Is there a way to remove the vertical white space?.

Honestly I didn't know what I was doing, was just trying to solve the issue but I dont really know. Can it be done? Is there an actual way to get it without huge extra vertical space?

Thanks to anyone who can help and for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap `Style`d objects with `ToString[#, StandardForm]&` and `StringJoin` them:

```
StringJoin[
  ToString[Style[Subscript[t, 2 g], 48, FontFamily -> "Lucida Handwriting"], StandardForm],
  ToString[Style[" Element", 32, Red, FontFamily -> "Old English Text MT"], StandardForm]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can combine elements with different styles using `Row`:

```
Row[{Style[Subscript[t, 2 g], 48, FontFamily -> "Lucida Handwriting"],
   Style[" Element", 32, Red, FontFamily -> "Old English Text MT", 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You learn something new every day :)