# How can we add two legends for same data?

Tags: plotting, legending

```
    Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"fx", "fy"}, Above]]
```

[image]

How can we add another label to the left like this:

[image]

Comment: `PlotLegends -> {Placed[ ..], Placed[ ..]}`

Comment: @Syed, may u please post an answer? `PlotLegends -> {Placed[{"fx", "fy"}, Above], 
  Placed[{"x", "y"}, Above]}` did not work

Comment: not working too

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTGOS.png) on v12.2.0Win7-x64.

Comment: that is not what I would like to see. kindly see 2nd [fig ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGYeP.png)  in the question green labels x and y

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer from [187933](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187933/have-a-string-of-letters-with-different-font-sizes-linelegend) by@kglr:

```
strx = StringJoin[
  ToString[Style[x, Darker@Green, 14, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   StandardForm]
  , ToString[Style[" \[LongDash]", 14, Red, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   StandardForm]
  , ToString[Style[" fx", 14, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   StandardForm]
  ];
stry = StringJoin[
  ToString[Style[y, Darker@Green, 14, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   StandardForm]
  , ToString[Style[" \[LongDash]", 14, Blue, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   StandardForm]
  , ToString[Style[" fy", 14, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
   StandardForm]
  ];

Plot[{
  Sin[x], Cos[x]
  }
 , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
 , PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[{"fx", "fy"}, Above]
   , Placed[PointLegend[{White, White}, {strx, stry}], Left]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: now if I change the  `PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}` we need to change `strx` and  `stry`